# ubuntu sudo password not accepted

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can access to my ubuntu server (V 16.10) using root password via ssh properly. But if I used the terminal for sudo commands, it got the message -> “Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported”. /etc/sudoers as follows

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbi$
# Host alias specification
# User alias specification
# Cmnd alias specification
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

02) I got this sudoers record through the Recovery Mode.

03) I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: This should be going to https://superuser.com/

Comment: Note the first comment, but `usermod -G sudo username` might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly confirm as which user you are running sudo command

For example if you are running sudo command as p1

P1 user should have an entry in /etc/sudoers

Below should be p1 entry format should be /etc/sudoers

P1 ALL=(ALL) commandspath

Then execute command sudo su p1

Then run the command sudo command

Comment: when I open /etc/sudoers the following message displays. visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

Comment: use visudo -f  /etc/sudoers